# VirtualBox USB settings are disabled. How can I change USB settings?

Tags: windows-7, usb, virtualbox

My goal is to access thumb drives and MP3 players from a VM. I have VB 5.1.14 installed on a Windows 10 host, running a Windows 7 Pro guest VM. I have the 5.1.14 Guest Additions installed on the VM, and I have the latest extension pack installed on the host. When I go into VirtualBox Manager, and open USB Settings for my VM, the settings are disabled/greyed out. USB is selected, and the version 1.1 radio button is checked. I assume I need EHCI or xHCI selected to be able to access USB 2.0 or USB 3.0 devices. In the VM, if I open 'Devices' - 'USB' after plugging in a thumb drive, there are two additional entries ("Unknown device" and "Generic USB2.0-..."), but clicking either of them doesn't access the USB stick. (It makes a couple of sounds, but they don't meaning anything to me.) How can I enable the disabled settings? What do I need to do to use my USB devices from my VM?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you try changing the USB settings while the VM is powered up. Most of the settings for a VM can not be changed while the VM is booted up.

So in order to change the USB settings, power down the Virtual Machine, and when it says "Powered Off" in the Virtual Box Manager for this VM then open its settings and see if you can perform the wanted changes.

Comment: Not powered up, but in a '**Saved**' state. That was it!   Thank you.